# Polymer app in sub-folder

Tags: polymer

Sorry if my question is trivial, but I am new to Polymer.

I have gone through the Polymer CLI tutorial, here:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up

I have created the app in a sub-folder on my server, here:
https://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~in9352/web-components/polymer/my-app/

But as you can see in the browser console, I am getting errors relating to the base URL, and the fact that Polymer seems to be looking for files on the root by default.

Now I have just read all sorts of advice on the web, tried different things, but no success. I have reverted all my failed attempts back to the fresh install (I think).

Where do I go from here?

Cheers :)

Comment: same, not solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298557/how-to-set-baseurl-in-polymer-starter-kit

Comment: The link to your site is dead.  It is likely this question will be flagged and taken down for not being reproducible.  If you're still having issues, include some of your code and your error messages in your post.